# How to Dynamically Add Controls to Delphi Form

Tags: delphi

I am trying to dynamically add button controls to an application. The application I'm working on has up to 6 different pre-defined button positions which can be any one of several different operations. For example, if the user presses the "New" button, I want to dynamically show a "Save", "Clear" and "Cancel" buttons and have each of the `OnClick` events point to the proper procedure/function. Each of the buttons are defined in an array of `TButton` and assigned as needed to the pre-defined buttons on the form.

This is a sample program I built to help understand what I'm trying to achieve:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnPos1: TButton;
    procedure btnNewClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Form1Close(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure Form1Create(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    procedure LoadButtons;
  end;

var
    Form1: TForm1;
    FormBtns: array[1..20] of TButton;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.LoadButtons;
begin
    FormBtns[1].Caption:='&New';
    FormBtns[1].OnClick:=btnNewClick;
    FormBtns[1].Left:=340;
    FormBtns[1].Top:=20;

    btnPos1.Caption:=FormBtns[1].Caption;
    btnPos1.OnClick:=FormBtns[1].OnClick;
    btnPos1.Left:=FormBtns[1].Left;
    btnPos1.Top:=FormBtns[1].Top;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnNewClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    // do something
end;

procedure TForm1.Form1Close(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
    Application.Terminate();
end;

procedure TForm1.Form1Create(Sender: TObject);
begin
    LoadButtons;
end;

end.
```

When this test and actual application runs I receive the following error:

`Project BtnTest.exe raised exception class $C0000005 with message 'c0000005 ACCESS_VIOLATION'.`

It is occurring on the following code:

`FormBtns[1].OnClick:=btnNewClick;`

I am assuming that it can't reconcile the `btnNewClick` reference for some reason but I don't understand why. I'm not even sure if this is best way to get the job done. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When the main form is closed, the app terminates automatically. No need for calling ``Application.Terminate`` at all in the ``OnClose`` event!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared an array of `TButton` *object pointers*, but you have not pointed them at anything yet.  You have to actually create the `TButton` objects before you can access their properties, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.LoadButtons;
begin
  FormBtns[1] := TButton.Create(Self);
  FormBtns[1].Parent := Self;
  ...
end;
```

`FormBtns` should also be a member of your `TForm1` class instead of a global variable.

Comment: "*I converted the test app*" - meaning what? Converted from what? I suggest you create a fresh project and try again.

Comment: I converted the app shown above to reflect your comments. I figured it out just now. The error has been resolved. Thanks for your input.